# Error: invalid length parameter passed to the right function in name parsing script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I gotta problem. When I run the below code I get an error saying:

invalid length parameter passed to the right function. What does that mean and how can it go away? Its to parse a name like smith, steve s to steve r smith in columns firstname, middlename and lastname

```
UPDATE table5
SET lastName = LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) - 1), 
    firstname = SUBSTRING(Name, 
                          CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2, 
                          CASE 
                            WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) = 0 THEN LEN(Name) + 1 
                            ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2)
                          END - CHARINDEX(', ', Name) - 2
                         ),
    middlename= RIGHT(Name, 
                      LEN(Name) - CASE 
                                    WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) = 0 THEN LEN(Name) 
                                    ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) 
                                 END
                    )
```

the "name" column is varchar (50) and firstname, middlename and lastname columns are also set to varchar (50) . I'm kinda stumped.. thanks in advance

Comment: Will help a lot if you put the possible data format in Name. Because your example isnt clear. Is there a coma `,`?  is there a space? is there a middle name?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because `CHARINDEX()` is returning 0 and `SUBSTRING()` require at number bigger than 0. Your assumption is correct string without middle name will give you error.

Can you check this fiddle and let me know if that is the format you are using for name. Because the Gordon Linoff query seem to be working for select

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cddd44/2)

**NOTE:**

I update the SqlFiddle with

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(', ', Name) > 0
```

My guess is some of your name doesnt have `,`

You can validate doing

```
SELECT Name
FROM test
WHERE CHARINDEX(', ', Name) = 0
```

You can also check your other CHARINDEX condition with your data to see which one RETURN 0

Comment: Please check the fiddle and let me know if that is name format. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f494c/2

Comment: yes the format looks good but I validated and every record has a comma. And yes when I run a select its just fine, but when there is an update command it blows up :(

Comment: Can you try to find what name is giving you problem? Like update 100 row, if error update lower 50 or top 50?

Comment: I believe it had to do with the comma being not in a particular row. I created a table with 3 names and it did work so I'll  run a delete command where the name doesn't contain a comma and see where that takes me and try again...

Comment: maybe the problem is coma+space and you have a record with only coma. You dont have to delete, just do a select as i show in my answer

Comment: no def not that as I ran a script to turn ',' into ', ' prior to trying an update. It is most likely dirty data somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to write a function, Here is the code.

```
IF object_id(N'udf_NameSplitter', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION udf_NameSplitter
GO

CREATE FUNCTION udf_NameSplitter
(    
      @FullName VARCHAR(50),
      @NameSplitCharacter CHAR(1),
      @NamePart CHAR(50) /*FN-firstname,MN-middlName,LN-lastName*/
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT, @NameTblString VARCHAR(50)

      DECLARE @NameTbl TABLE (ID INT Identity(1,1),Item NVARCHAR(1000))

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@FullName, LEN(@FullName) - 1, LEN(@FullName)) <> @NameSplitCharacter
      BEGIN
            SET @FullName = @FullName + @NameSplitCharacter
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@NameSplitCharacter, @FullName) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@NameSplitCharacter, @FullName)

            INSERT INTO @NameTbl(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@FullName, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @FullName = SUBSTRING(@FullName, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@FullName))
      END

      SELECT @NameTblString = LTRIM(RTRIM(Item))
      FROM @NameTbl 
      WHERE ID = CASE WHEN @NamePart = 'LN' THEN 1 WHEN @NamePart = 'FN' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END

      RETURN (@NameTblString)
END
GO
```

Test the function with a few scenarios. I think I covered most but its worth having a second look. I would highly recommend doing a select before an update and see if the data is accurate or as expected.

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50) = 'lastName   , firstname ,middleName '

SELECT 
lastName=dbo.udf_NameSplitter(@Name,',','LN'),
firstname=dbo.udf_NameSplitter(@Name,',','FN'),
middleName=dbo.udf_NameSplitter(@Name,',','MN')
```

Usage with your table

```
UPDATE table5
SET lastName=LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) - 1), 
    firstname=SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) = 0 THEN LEN(Name) + 1 ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) END - CHARINDEX(', ', Name) - 2),
     middlename=RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) = 0 THEN LEN(Name) ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) END)
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that `charindex()` is returning 0, which you are passing to another function.  One way to fix this is:

```
UPDATE table5
    SET lastName=LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) - 1), 
        firstname=SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) = 0 THEN LEN(Name) + 1 ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) END - CHARINDEX(', ', Name) - 2),
         middlename=RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) = 0 THEN LEN(Name) ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', Name, CHARINDEX(', ', Name) + 2) END) 
    WHERE Name LIKE '% % %';
```

This ensures that `Name` has two spaces, which your logic is assuming.

Comment: also not sure if it matters but at times the names are smith, steve with no middlename ..

Answer (score -1):

```
select left(RTRIM(ltrim(C_Subarea_Code)),2) +
       right(RTRIM(ltrim(C_Subarea_Code)),len(RTRIM(ltrim(C_Subarea_Code)))-3) 
from Tbl_Doc_Stock_Chem_Add_Mst
```

in sql

Comment: Please give some explanation as to what is different about your answer.