# Cannot create a Computed column using RIGHT function because CHARINDEX returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

So I have a Document table where I want to add a computed column named `FileType` using the column `FileName`. Below is the code I used to add a Computed Column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Document
Add FileType AS UPPER(RIGHT(FileName,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(FileName))-1))
```

It turns out some of the data in `FileName` column does not have a `'.'` in their name which is causing the issue. I want to somehow implement a check to return `CharIndex` of only those data consisting of a `'.'` in their `FileName`. But I cannot write a `Select` statement in the `Alter` statement.

NOTE: I tried to find solution from following links which helped me find the issue but I could not derive any solution from them.

[Error: invalid length parameter passed to the right function in name parsing script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444557/error-invalid-length-parameter-passed-to-the-right-function-in-name-parsing-scr)

[Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661084/invalid-length-parameter-passed-to-the-right-function)

[Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function in update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616694/invalid-length-parameter-passed-to-the-right-function-in-update-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a case expression to make it conditional e.g.

```
UPPER(RIGHT(FileName, case when CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(FileName)) > 0 then CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(FileName))-1 else len(Filename) end))
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is to add the delimiter:

```
UPPER(RIGHT(FileName, CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(FileName) + '.') - 1))
```

No conditional logic is needed.